# Extract Insert statements from Oracle DB through Shell script

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell, unix

I want to extract the insert statements for the data in a table in Oracle DB through the shell script. It would be similar to DB backup but I need insert statements for data in all tables in DB.

Comment: Guys ... please help if one have done this kind of task !!

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, you can use user_tab_columns (to get tables and column names if you need only for objects in your own schema), construct the query to get data out and glue them to output string INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, ...) values(numericValue, "charValue", ...); .  Also, special care about huge BLOB values, date/timestamp format, nulls etc. It is doable but likely not the best tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . ... if not this way ... Can you suggest how can i achieve this other way ? I need the insert statements of tables for a particular condition but can't do it manually as number of tables are huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is : 
Extract all insert statement for all tables in database, than run those insert in different database ? Or wish to save these insert statement for future use ?

If above requirement is true, their are better way to achieve this. Insert statement with "data" shown expose data to anyone who can read these extract & a serious security threat. You should look for using datapump for this requirement.

- Abhi

Comment: Thanks Abhishek .. I'll look at it and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have TOAD for Oracle you can exact the results of a query from Data Grid of a Editor window.  Click the Export Dataset button above the resulting data set and select insert statements.

Comment: I can use GUI but I want to extract for all tables in DB so i need some other solution . By the way thanks for your response

Comment: You can script everything that way igr suggested above.  You can create a dmp file either command line or using TOAD. You can use data pump to export everything